# Best way to switch UI in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are building a mobile app built in Unity3D, which involves a lot of UI switch. For example, from this page to the other page, it involves a lot of disabling the previous UI and activate new UI elements.

A common way to do is to set old UI inactive and new UI active. When switch back, just deactive/active again. But I read that this will cuase [Rebuild](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/fundamentals-unity-ui) problem (`Canvas.SendWillRenderCanvases` or `BuildBatch`). I wonder what is the alternative?

Will these two solutions work?

1. Instead of activate/deactivate UI element, apply it on the UI canvas.
2. Deactivae the UI element by moving it far away. Will it cause UI Rect rebuild?
3. Set in different layer, change its layer to invisbile layer when deactivate.

Answer (score 3):

I would discourage you from using a state machine for your UI if you consider developing an application with many UI layers.

It will result in a scene hierarchy with hundreds of objects, some of them only been used when going deep down the app (like settings of a specific page) but they end up in memory at all time.

Also, it makes things harder to debug since you cannot really jump to a specific state without going through all the previous ones (except if you are already advanced prog and you defined your classes so they can work from anywhere).

The easy solution is to use scenes to separate your states, just like it is done in Android/iOS with Activity/Fragments or views.

This will clean you memory when needed, you can still keep scenes alive on the stack (like mobile OS does) using additive scene loading, since you won't have a lot of objects to create, the scene changes will seem seamless. 
You can easily reuse code over scenes with inheritance and extension with scene name:

```
public class MyUIClassWithManyCommonCode:MonoBehaviour{}
public class FrontPage : MyUIClassWithManyCommonCode{}
public class CatalogPage : MyUIClassWithManyCommonCode{}
```

And finally since, you limit the amount of objects in a scene to only what should be seen, it is easy to find an object in the scene.

Comment: But if in one scene, it involves a lot of active/deactive UI, for example, Hide or Show the navigation bar, which methods above do you recommend?

Comment: Not sure, but I would try having multiple child canvases with each state as a canvas. When a new canvas is needed, it would cover the previous one avoiding the redraw since the previous one would not get marked as dirty. You would stack the canvas as you go down the state. To be tested.